How to pass slots through from Parent to Child Components with PrimeVue?
I am trying to wrap some PrimeVue components to make my own component library. But how do I handle all the slots?
Some PrimeVue components have a large number of slots so passing each one individually would be a massive pain.
Fortunately, I found this solution to pass all slots from Parent to Child Component.
Here is an example in use with the PrimeVue Dropdown component:
<Dropdown v-bind="$attrs" >
  <template v-for="(_, name) in $slots" #[name]="scope">
    <slot :name v-bind="scope" />
  </template>
</Dropdown>

Unfortunately, it doesn't work with PrimeVue because TypeScript it gives this error on #[name] regarding no index signature on DropdownSlots:

Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string | number' can't be used to index type 'DropdownSlots'.
No index signature with a parameter of type 'string' was found on type 'DropdownSlots'. ts(7053)

Any ideas for a workaround?

It's good that you find an answer but the question wasn't well defined. The solutions would be different for 2 and 3. "it doesn't work with PrimeVue because TypeScript it gives this error" - this two things are presumably unrelated. That there's type problem doesn't necessarily prevent it from working. Vue itself doesn't use types in templates, these are third-party tools like vue-tsc and ides. Any way, the solution is to use render function that provides more flexibility. The lib you linked does this

Thanks for the extra info, but I'm still not sure how to implement what you're describing here. If you would like to provide an answer that has the render function solution then I will accept that answer, because I believe a code solution would be more helpful to others than a package which hides the inner workings.

I posted. The lib is also helpful because it's not always convenient to switch to render when a template already exists and it's not small

I found this fantastic package called Vue Forward Slots to solve all these issues related to forwarding slots: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-forward-slots
I am using it like this to forward all slots (including the default slot):
  <ForwardSlots :exclude="[]">
    <Dropdown v-bind="$attrs" />
  </ForwardSlots>

I hope someday something like this makes it's way into core vue.js.

That there's TypeScript error doesn't mean code is wrong. Vue templates aren't currently type-safe by design and require third-party tools (vue-tsc, IDEs) for type checking that can have their own quirks.
It's easier to transform children and props in render function instead of a template, this also avoids the problems associated with the use of types in a template. For a simple wrapper component it is:
setup(props, { slots }) {
  return () => h(Dropdown, props, slots);
}

